# Flashcache Power Failure

Tags: flashcache

iam using ssd for caching other disks ( flashcache module )
if a power failure happened write operations will just stop suddenly and lead to bad sector due to incomplete cache back to devices ( sata disks )
so is there is a way to continue get cache from ssd to devices ( disks ) after server startup, as the cache already stored on ssd?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: hi
iam using ssd for caching other disks ( flashcache module )
if a power failure happened write operations will just stop suddenly and lead to bad sector due to incomplete cache back to devices ( sata disks )
so is there is a way to continue get cache from ssd to devices ( disks )

thanks

Comment: That is not how bad sectors happen.  That is a physical problem, not a data problem.

Comment: hi falcon
power failure would make some bad sector if is there sensitive io running 
please read this http://www.howtogeek.com/173463/bad-sectors-explained-why-hard-drives-get-bad-sectors-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually after testing flashcache using write-back cache method i were able to continue getting already stored cache on ssd back to cached disks after power failure or a crash normally using flashcache_load.
It looks like the official documentation is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to protect your site/facility power first. Please use an appropriately-sized UPS with enough run time.

Beyond that, I'm an advocate of quality SSDs. You want to use a good SSD with a super-capacitor onboard to protect in-flight data.

If you're asking about general cache persistence, that's another topic.

Comment: hi
iam using ssd for caching other disks ( flashcache module )
if a power failure happened write operations will just stop suddenly and lead to bad sector due to incomplete cache back to devices ( sata disks )
so is there is a way to continue get cache from ssd to devices ( disks )

thanks

Comment: @user205537 Protect your server with a battery backup unit. Talking about other situations without taking this basic step is not reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/flashcache/blob/master/doc/flashcache-doc.txt):

```
It is important to note that in the first cut, cache writes are
non-atomic, ie, the "Torn Page Problem" exists. In the event of a
power failure or a failed write, part of the block could be written,
resulting in a partial write. We have ideas on how to fix this and
provide atomic cache writes (see the Futures section).
```

So it sounds like flashcache can't do what you want.

Comment: Sadly this is the true flashcache can't do that :D 
i got it before i opened this topic but i thought there is might be an solution.